# No_connection_could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

hi i creating a Local Chat System. 
i created a program as server listener and a Client using Console app(as server) and Forms(as Client) on and i used the Sockets as Communication with port:9999.
if i open both program on the local machine it works, but as i soon try to connect from another computer it fails and i have a message

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

i tried to deactivate firewall and Antivirus but it didn't seceded, i work with laptop and PC on the same router. 
here a code for Server

### Client code

```
private void Server_Connection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectDone.Reset();
        Server.workSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
            Server.IPEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(GetMyIP()), 9999);//gets the local IP of the Device
        else
            Server.IPEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), 9999);
        Server.workSocket.BeginConnect(Server.IPEnd, new AsyncCallback(ServerCallback), Server);//begin connect
        connectDone.WaitOne();
        if (Server.workSocket.Connected)
        {

            listenServer = new Thread(ServerContacts);//starting a thread that gets the msg from server
            listenServer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Server Code

```
public static void SetupServer()
    {
        Socket lisetner = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Server.workSocket = lisetner;
        try
        {
            lisetner.Bind(IPEnd);
            lisetner.Listen(100);
            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
                lisetner.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), lisetner);//beging Accept Clients to server 
                allDone.WaitOne();//waiting untill when someone joins
                SendToAll();//sending all client the name's of all client

            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message + "\n" + err.Source);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The client need to connect to server IP address.  Your client is trying to connect to itself instead of remote machine : IPAddress.Parse(GetMyIP()), 9999

Comment: @jdweng I believe this is an answer, not a comment. Could you please add it as an answer?